# Компоненты для работы с Excel и Word в Delphi XE(1,2,3)

Tags: ms-word, delphi, excel

Добрый день! В делфи 7 существовали хорошие компоненты для работы с Excel и Word'ом. Куда исчезли эти компоненты в новых версиях delphi линейки XE? Где их взять, как установить, чтобы работать с ними?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снимается. Оказывается, при установке этот компонент по умолчанию почему-то не подключился. Если кому-то поможет: Component->InstallPackages->Microsoft Office XP Server.

Answer (score 1):

Пользуюсь NativeXLS - хорошие и мощьные классы. Шустро работают, поддерживают формулы, изображения почти все что есть в Excel. Поддерживают как xls, так и xlsx. 
Ещё есть XLSReadAndWriteII, ими не пользовался.